# How to show or set datepicker dialog for a textview that is inside a fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-datepicker

I am absolute beginner to Android. I am trying to set text for text field inside inside a fragment using datepicker dialog.

This is the fragment of text field inside an activity

```
public class CreateTaskFragment extends Fragment{
    private Button saveBtn;
    private EditText tfDescription,tfDate;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_task,container,false);

        tfDescription = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.tf_task_description);
        tfDate = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.tf_task_date);
        tfDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment pickerFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
                pickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"DatePicker");
            }
        });

        saveBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_save_task);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveTask();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void saveTask()
    {
        String description = tfDescription.getText().toString();
        String date = tfDate.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

This is the dialog fragment for picker

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
    }
    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        //set the date here

    }

}
```

My question is how to set the selected date for the text field of the previous fragment. Datepicker is working and I do not know how to set selected date for edit text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give you simple solution, just replace the code in the OnClick with this

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    String date = "Date"+String.valueOf(year) +"-"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear)
                            +"-"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                    tfDescription.setText(date);
                    tfDate.setText(date);
                }
            }, yy, mm, dd);
            datePicker.show();
```

You will see the EditText of tfDescription/tfDate changed after you pick a date

Comment: Throwing error . 01-24 10:00:16.536 7414-7414/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.waiyanhein.todo.todo.CreateTaskFragment.getContext

Comment: Are you sure? It works in my computer. ok try to change `getContext` with `getActivity()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked after I replaced with getActivity().

Comment: I will green up the answer soon.

Comment: Good! try to understand the callback function which is key knowledge to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date to the EditText of description. Such as:

```
 @Override
 public void onDateSet(DatePicker dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    //set the text of description
    tfDescription.setText("Year:" + year + " Month: " + monthOfYear + "Day: " + dayOfMonth);
    //get the data of date by using Calendar
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
    mCurrentDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

It means that you can access the data of Date in the `@Override public void onDateSet`

Comment: How come I can access tfDate reference from PickerFragment because it is in different fragment. Can I get answer in details precisely please ?

Comment: Wait a minute, I give you a complete example

Comment: You can try to implement the interface `implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` for the fragment, and then `@Override onDateSet` in fragment which can access the EditText easier.

Comment: In which fragment do I have to override ? I already override one in selectDatePickerFragment.

Comment: `public class CreateTaskFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListene{  @Override onDateSet(){ access the EditText}}`

Comment: I made this [demo](https://github.com/xinmeng1/datepickerdemo) for you, it works. You don't need this fragment `SelectDateFragment` if you just want to pick date and get the date. If you want to use more advance datepicker, you can try this one [android-betterpickers](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers). I am using it in my project.

Comment: By the way, try to understand the **callback** function which is key knowledge to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create constructor for SelectDateFragment that will get EditText reference and in onDate() you can set the date to that reference. Simple as that.

Comment: Can I get code sample? Because I am creating like this in pickerFragment. But it is showing error with red underline. public SelectDateFragment(EditText textField)
    {
        
    }